# Pass a string value from one view controller to another

Tags: iphone

I am using this way to pass a string value from one view controller to another but still it's not working. Please help! From the main menu login method I pass a result value of a web service to SecondMenu:

```
- (IBAction)MainMenuLogin_Method:(id)sender
{
    SecondMenu *lc2=[[SecondMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondMenu" bundle:nil];

    lc2.username_TextField.text=@"hello";// in actual it is a soap result

    //[self presentModalViewController:lc2 animated:YES];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:lc2.view];
}
```

Comment: Define "not working". What behavior are you expecting by not seeing?

Comment: the textfield is empty, it does not display the string hello.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the `username_TextField` property is not linked to the actual UITextView. (1) Check that the property definition of `username_TextField` in the `SecondMenu` header is defined as an IBOutlet and that (2) it is actually linked up in Interface Builder.

Edit:

Looking at the full code at your link, it looks like the `username_TextField` property is a property of the Class `LoginController` but in this code you have instance `lcv2` as Class `SecondMenu`. There is nothing in the code you provided to show that the `SecondMenu` Class has a `username_TextField` property. If you initialize `lcv2` as an instance of `LoginController` the code above will work assuming you have the outlets wired correcting in interface builder.

Comment: i have pasted the entire code , please check this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693783/how-to-pass-a-string-value-from-one-controller-to-another.

Comment: You haven't pasted the entire code because there is no class definition for `SecondMenu` in either post. If SecondMenu either lacks the `username_TextField` property or it is not connected in the nib, the text field will not populate.