# how to pass a string value from one controller to another

Tags: iphone

I have a login controller ,and after the successful login i want to pass some string value to the menu page.however it does not work.the application crashes.
I have tried possible suggesstion of Ihuk and SAM  from the link below

[how to pass a string value from one view controller to another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685964/how-to-pass-a-string-value-from-one-view-controller-to-another-view-controller)

loginController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class RootViewController;
@class Menu;

@interface LoginController : UIViewController {
  UIButton *login_Button;
  UITextField *username_TextField;
  UITextField *password_TextField;
  RootViewController *mc1;
  UINavigationController *navigationController;
  Menu *mv1;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *login_Button;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *username_TextField;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *password_TextField;
@property(nonatomic,retain) RootViewController *mc1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet 
         UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property(nonatomic,retain)Menu *mv1;

- (IBAction)Login_Method:(id)sender;
-(id)initWithUserName:(NSString *)name ;
@end
```

loginController.m

```
#import "LoginController.h"
#import "Menu.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation LoginController

@synthesize mc1,mv1;
@synthesize login_Button,username_TextField,password_TextField;
@synthesize navigationController;


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after 
// loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
  if (![self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden])
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
//[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

  // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
  // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
  // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (IBAction)Login_Method:(id)sender
{           
  Menu *mv2 = [[Menu alloc] initWithUserName:@"Menu" bundle:nil];
  //mv2.l1.text=@"aa"; //i tried this, but not work,so created initWithUserName
  self.mv1=mv2;
  [self presentModalViewController:mv1 animated:YES];
//  [RootViewController release];
}

-(id)initWithUserName:(NSString *)name 
{
  self = [super init];
  if (nil == self) {
    return nil;
  }

  // display or store login info somewhere
  [mv1.l1 setText:name];

  return self;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {  
  [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [username_TextField release];
  [password_TextField release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Menu.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Menu;
@interface Menu : UIViewController {    
  UILabel *l1;
  UIButton *AccountSummary_Button;
  UIButton *PayOffQuote_Button;
  UIButton *PayBill_Button;
  UIButton *Logout_Button;
  UINavigationController *nv1;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *l1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *AccountSummary_Button;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *PayOffQuote_Button;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *PayBill_Button;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Logout_Button;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *nv1;

-(IBAction)ViewAccountSummary_method:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)ViewPayOffQuote_method:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)ViewPayBill_method:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Logout_method:(id)sender;

@end
```

Menu.m

Comment: Indent code with 4 spaces so it gets properly formatted. Read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more info (also accessible by clicking the orange question mark above the answer entry field)

Comment: While running it in the simulator, go to Run, Console.  Then proceed to log in and let the app crash.  What is the error logged at the bottom of the Console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a string value from one view controller to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692984/pass-a-string-value-from-one-view-controller-to-another)

Answer (score 1):

Make a property in your application delegate, for example, an `NSString*` called `myString`.

Then access it from the login controller and other controllers like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].myString
```

You could, for example, set `myString`'s value in the login controller:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].myString = @"value";
```

You could read it in any other controller:

```
NSLog(@"myString is: %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].myString);
```

Additionally, some Cocoa style tips:

1. Do not capitalize class members (`AccountSummary_Button` etc.)
2. Do not capitalize class methods (`ViewAccountSummary_method` etc.)

The only thing you should capitalize are the classes themselves (`Menu` etc.).